# Why is 'static lifetime required for references returned from methods in an impl for a trait object?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

When I don't include the `+ 'static` in this code, `rustc` complains. Why?

```rs
// adapted from rust-analyzer https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer
trait Upcast<T: ?Sized> {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &T;
}

trait DefDatabase {}
trait HirDatabase: Upcast<dyn DefDatabase> {}

struct RootDatabase{}
impl Upcast<dyn DefDatabase> for RootDatabase {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &(dyn DefDatabase + 'static) {
        &*self
    }
}
```

```
`impl` item signature doesn't match `trait` item signature
expected `fn(&RootDatabase) -> &(dyn DefDatabase + 'static)`
   found `fn(&RootDatabase) -> &dyn DefDatabase`
the lifetime requirements from the `impl` do not correspond to the
requirements in the `trait`
verify the lifetime relationships in the `trait` and `impl` between the
`self` argument, the other inputs and its output
```

Why is `'static` lifetime required?

It seems like the `dyn` is essential to the example. `rustc` does not complain about this impl, which doesn't mention `'static`:

```rs
impl Upcast<RootDatabase> for RootDatabase {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &Self {
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the question was unclear. You may have missed "When I don't include the + 'static in this code, rustc complains." [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=24a1c0b27aa221f5a9b6360e53217679)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly state what the lifetime of the *Trait Object* `&'dyn DefDatabase` is so that the borrow checker knows what the lifetime of any references held by the struct behind the pointer are. `'static` is the default if you do not define it, or it cannot otherwise be determined from the context. See [default trait object lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) in the rust language reference for more information.

Adding a lifetime to your `Upcast` trait definition allows you to drop `'static`.

```rust
trait Upcast<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &T; // 'a is not necessary here because the generic `T` may or may not be a trait object
}

trait DefDatabase {}

struct RootDatabase{}
impl DefDatabase for RootDatabase {}

impl<'a> Upcast<'a, dyn DefDatabase> for RootDatabase {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &(dyn DefDatabase + 'a) { // now we can replace 'static with 'a
        &*self
    }
}

impl<'a> Upcast<'a, RootDatabase> for RootDatabase {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &Self { // &Self is not a trait object, so no trait object lifetime is necessary
        self
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

It should be noted that this lifetime is *not* the lifetime of the reference *to* the trait object, which can be declared separately and is the reason for why the lifetime must be disambiguated with parenthesis.

```rust
impl<'a> Upcast<'a, dyn DefDatabase> for RootDatabase {
    fn upcast<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b (dyn DefDatabase + 'a) { // 'b is elided
        &*self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage to making this change (being generic over lifetime)? I couldn't find any difference in expressiveness. (this is a follow-on question, marked your answer as correct)